# polymer absolute image position

Tags: html, css, polymer

I'm trying to learn Google Polymer, but I seem to fail at really simple things...

I currently have a drawer and a main page with a title bar as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <!-- 1. Load platform.js for polyfill support. -->
  <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>

  <!-- 2. Use an HTML Import to bring in the element. -->
  <link rel="import"
  href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="big-picture.html">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">

</head>
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">

  <core-drawer-panel>

    <div drawer id="drawer">
      <core-menu id="drawermenu">
        <paper-item class="menulink">Home</paper-item>
        <paper-item class="menulink">Gallery</paper-item>
        <paper-item class="menulink">Calendar</paper-item>
        <paper-item class="menulink">Contact</paper-item>
      </core-menu>
    </div>

    <div main>
      <core-header-panel mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar>
          <core-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="{{menuAction}}"></core-icon-button>
          <h1 id="title">Test</h1>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div id="pagecontent">
          <big-picture></big-picture>
        </div>
      </core-header-panel>
    </div>

  </core-drawer-panel>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a picture element that will be shown directly beneath the title bar,
I want the picture to fill up the remaining screen space but also have a certain height. Later I want these pictures to change automatically. None of my styling seems to work though, my picture element looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="big-picture">

<template>
    <style>

    :host
    {
        height: 100px;
    }
    #crop
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    #mainpictop
    {
        position: absolute;
    }
    #mainpicbottom
    {
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="crop">
        <img id="mainpictop" src="img/main/1.jpg"></img>
        <img id="mainpicbottom" src="img/main/2.jpg"></img>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
Polymer({});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: `Polymer()` needs a name of the element AFAIK. And if you're not passing any data, you can just add the `noscript` attribute to your `<polymer-element>`.

Comment: Hi, I added the noscript attribute, but this doesn't really make any difference.  I added the script tags to implement the photo cycling later. My element gets shown, but not with the correct width or height

Comment: It wasn't an answer to your problem, just a comment about your code setup.

Comment: You can leave the name out of the `Polymer()` invocation if your code is in an import. The name is only required if your code is in the main document or is not inside of the `<polymer-element>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common problem is not setting up your page layout. Container elements generally need to be sized explicitly. I would suggest something like this:

```
<body fullbleed vertical layout unresolved touch-action="auto">
  <core-drawer-panel flex>
```

`fullbleed` makes the body fit the viewport with no margin. `vertical layout` gives body flex-box layout ability. `flex` on the `core-drawer-panel` will cause it to fit to the body.

Additionally, all custom elements are `display: inline` by default (this is a DOM/CSS rule, not Polymer's). To set a size on an element, you need to make it `block` or `inline-block`.

```
:host
{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}
```